# Quick & neat Mma actions

Tags: functions, documentation

I know that the expressions `Series[Exp[x],{x,0,2}]` and `Exp[x]+O[x]^3`are equivalent in *Mathematica*. I was wondering if a similar syntax applies for `Limit` or any other function?
Where can I look for or read about such "shortcuts"?

Comment: Technically, they are not equivalent.  They just happen to lead to the same result in the cases you have tried.  For example, `Series[Exp[1/x] BesselK[1, 1/x], {x, 0, 2}]` and `Exp[1/x] BesselK[1, 1/x] + O[x]^3` do not agree.

Answer (score 2):

You can enter `5 10^6` as `5*^6` and save two characters, although I don't think that's really worthwhile or improves readability.

`Limit` can be entered as <kbd>Esc</kbd> `lim` <kbd>Esc</kbd>with the limit in an underscript. Not sure whether you would consider that a shortcut.

Comment: Hey Sjoerd! Good to see you post again. :-)

Comment: Hey Mr.W! I'll drop by occasionally, but after 15 years of Mathematica forums it's difficult to stay interested all the time.

Comment: I understand and sympathize.  Thanks for saying hello.